# Dart spread operator to say "place this in list if it's not null"

Tags: dart

Is there a combination of Dart spread operators and null-aware operators that will do this?

```
[
  1, 
  ...twoOrNull() // this will be inserted only if it's null. something else than the ... operator will be here. 
  3, 
]
```

So the list will be either `[1, 2, 3]` or `[1, 3]`. I guess `twoOrNull()` can return `[2]` or `[]`, but it would be nice if it could return `2` or `null`.

Is this possible without introducing a variable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a null-aware spread operator (`...?`), but your `twoOrNull()` function would have to return either `[2]`or `null`; the spread operator expands an *iterable* within another collection literal, and it doesn't make sense to "spread" an `int`.

There's also Dart's collection-if construct, but it would require either calling `twoOrNull()` twice or saving the result in a variable:

```dart
[
  1, 
  if (twoOrNull() != null) twoOrNull(),
  3, 
]
```

See [the Lists section from the Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) for more information about spread and collection-if.

Comment: I didn't know about `...?`, that will come in handy for sure. Thank you. Actually there could be something like `?? twoOrNull()` that's in the same vein as the `if` we have here. Maybe this could be a nice suggestion for the language.

Comment: `??` is already used as a binary operator (e.g. `var x = mightBeNull ?? defaultValue`) and reusing it as a unary operator likely would make the grammar more complicated. I agree that it would be a useful language feature, and it's been requested in https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/219 and in https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/323.

Comment: Nice, thank you for linking to those issues. I had looked around but could not find them.

Answer (score 2):

An one-liner without side effect:

```
[
  1,
  ...[twoOrNull()]..removeWhere((x) => x == null),
  3,
]
```

The idea here is to map from an int `twoOrNull()` to a list of either `[2]` or `[]`, then use the spreading operator `...` to unfold it.

Note that having one `twoOrNull()` in this case is fine, but as soon as you start having more elements that need null checking before being added to the list, readability will suffer. In that case, consider delaying the null check to after you have added the element to the list, i.e.

```
[
  1,
  twoOrNull(),
  3,
]..removeWhere((x) => x == null)
```

This will make the code a lot more straightforward and readable.

**EDIT:**

For the best readability in the list, it would be perfect to have a `twoOrNullList()` function returning either `[2]` or `[]`. Then you can use it pretty much similar to what you proposed:

```
var twoOrNullList() => [twoOrNull()]..removeWhere((x) => x == null)
[
  1,
  ...twoOrNullList(),
  3,
]
```

Comment: I don't think it's very different than the `[if]` we currently have as far as readability etc. goes. I think it's even an improvement. Your suggestions definitely work, but the whole point is to not squint even for a second to understand what's going on. Which is what the spread and null aware operators currently provide for other scenarios.

Comment: The difference is that it doesn't have side effect, say if your `twoOrNull()` function prints something then the solution using `if` will print that twice, same for accessing database or requesting something from server. Other than that, they are the same.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'd like to have this operator, not to have to call the same function twice. This improves readability and efficiency by calling it only once. You were arguing against my suggestion saying that it would reduce readability, that's why I compared it to the `[if]`, which is clearly worse in this situation.

Comment: Yes, I was comparing the readability to the solution using if. Your proposed solution is not valid code thus I didn't compare to that at all. I get a sense that you feel I am rejecting your proposal, I am really not. There are a lot of useful operators that I would like Dart to have, but at the moment what you proposed can not be done with ease.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a `whereNotNull()` extension method on `List` contained in the official `collection` package ([pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)).

Using this might improve the readability a bit, e.g.:

```dart
[
  1,
  twoOrNull(),
  3,
].whereNotNull()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution.

```dart
Iterable<T> emit<T>(T? p) sync* {
  if (p != null) {
    yield p;
  }
}

[
  1,
  ...emit(twoOrNull()),
  3,
]
```